# Extracting relevant information from text in R - regex

Tags: r, regex, text-mining, information-extraction

I am trying to extract some information from a text document. I have converted this text document into a data frame using `pdftext().` Now I would like to extract the information I am after. Below is the code to create a dataframe like mine:

```
text <- data.frame(page = c(1,1,2,3), sen = c(1,2,1,1), text = c("Dear Mr case 1","the value of my property is £500,000.00 and it was built in 1980", 
                                                             "The protected percentage is 0% for 2 years", "The interest rate is fixed for 2 years at 4.8%"))
```

From the above dataframe, I need to extract the following:

1: Gender of the person. In this case it would be Male (looking at Mr)

2: The number that represents the property value. in this case would be £500,000.00.

3: The protected percentage value, which in our case would be 0%.

4: The interest rate value and in our case it is 4.8%.

Ideally I would like to output a data frame like below:

[image]

Even if I can extract these pieces of information separately, It is still good enough. I probably can use a regular expression, tell it to find a pattern like 'Protected Percentage' and then give me the number that appears right after it finds this pattern. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are right, regex would work but if your text varies a lot then it would fail. I would suggest you look into natural language processing (NLP) packages such as `koRpus` for better text mining.

Comment: How standardized is the data structure? For example, is it always four character strings per person? Is the surrounding text always the same? If so, some regex in this case would be trivial.

Comment: The structure is always the same in terms of the surrounding text. The person's name is not always the same length but overall everything else has a consistent format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression not working in R but works on website. Text mining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275752/regular-expression-not-working-in-r-but-works-on-website-text-mining)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can get all the parts of your R array into a single string, this regex would do the job (set it to be case insensitive):

```
dear\s+(mr|mrs|miss|ms)\b[^£]+(£[\d,.]+)(?:\D|\d(?![\d.]*%))+([\d.]+%)(?:\D|\d(?![\d.]*%))+([\d.]+%)
```

The matches are in capture groups 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Here is a demo (look in the matches pane on right-hand side):
https://regex101.com/r/OcVN5r/1

I don't really know R, but I understand you can do something like:

```
regmatches(subject, 
gregexpr("dear\\s+(mr|mrs|miss|ms)\\b[^£]+(£[\\d,.]+)(?:\\D|\\d(?![\\d.]*%))+([\\d.]+%)(?:\\D|\\d(?![\\d.]*%))+([\\d.]+%)",
subject, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE));
```

But I leave the R details up to you.

EDIT: Maybe this will work in R:

```
matches <- gregexpr("dear\\s+(mr|mrs|miss|ms)\\b[^£]+(£[\\d,.]+)(?:\\D|\\d(?![\\d.]*%))+([\\d.]+%)(?:\\D|\\d(?![\\d.]*%))+([\\d.]+%)", subject, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE);
result <- lapply(matches, function(m) attr(m, "capture.start")[,1])
for (i in seq_along(result))
  attr(result[[i]], "match.length") <- attr(matches[[i]], "capture.length")[,1]
result
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaifroid. I looked at your regex and on the demo it seems to be working fine. Tried on R didn't work. I also tried on the same webpage as you did by opening a new session and copying and pasting your regex along with the text. It didn't work on the website as well when I tried by opening a new session.

Comment: I was thinking of separating the whole regex into multiple steps and then combining their outputs. for instance. first get the Mr or Miss info, then get the number that appears after 'protected percentage'

Comment: Looking at your regex101, the issue is simply because you didn't set the regex to be case-insensitive. Click on the little "gm" that appears to the right of the regex at the top, and choose case-insensitive. With R did you use the `ignore.case=TRUE` options as I suggested above? EDIT: You can make the regex case-sensitive if you're sure that you'll always have Mr Mrs Miss Ms spelt with correct capital letter. In that case, just change those in the regex to use the initial capital. Also change `dear` to `Dear`.

Comment: I understand that if you do this in R:
`gregexpr("dear\\s+(mr|mrs|miss|ms)\\b[^£]+(£[\\d,.]+)(?:\\D|\\d(?![\\d.]*%))+([\\d.]+%)(?:\\D|\\d(?![\\d.]*%))+([\\d.]+%)", subject, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE);`
then you'll get a list with a vector of the positions and lengths of all the regex matches in each element. But I don't really know R.

Comment: I've added some more template code to my answer so you can see if you can adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial solution: a regex for each block you want to extract. You might have to adjust the regex or how you put things together in a data frame, but that should get you going. Note the R package `stringr` uses [ICU regex](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), and requires escaping with double back-slash.

```r
p_load(tidyverse)

ttt <- str_flatten(text$text)

# gender
gender_regex <- c("M.s*")
gender <- str_match(ttt, gender_regex)
```

`.` : any character (ie the `r` of `Mr` or `Mrs`, or the `s` of `Ms`)
`*` : repeat the `s` 0 or more times, as many as possible (ie 1 `s` from `Mrs` or 2 from `Miss`)

```r
# number property value
propval_regex <- regex("\U00A3\\d\\S++\\s")
property_value <- str_match(ttt, propval_regex) %>%
  str_trim()
```

`\U00A3` : unicode hex for British pound sign
`\\d` : any number
`\\S` : any non whitespace character (ie includes the thousand and decimal separators)
`++` : match 1 or more times
`\\s` : whitespace character

```r
# protected percentage value and interest rate
# regex for all percentages
r <- "\\d++\\.?+\\d?+\\%"

# vector of matches
percents <- str_match_all(ttt, r) %>%
  flatten_chr()

# each as its own variable
protected_percentage_value <- percents[1]
interest_rate <- percents[2]
```

`\\d` : any number
`++` : repeat 1 or more times
`\\.` : decimal separator
`?+` : repeat 0 or one time
`\\%` : the percent sign