# Regular expression not working in R but works on website. Text mining

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I have a regex which works on the regular expression website but doesn't work when I copy it in R. Below is the code to recreate my data frame:

```
text <- data.frame(page = c(1,1,2,3), sen = c(1,2,1,1),
                   text = c("Dear Mr case 1",
                            "the value of my property is £500,000.00 and it was built in 1980", 
                            "The protected percentage is 0% for 2 years",
                            "The interest rate is fixed for 2 years at 4.8%"))
```

regex working on website: https://regex101.com/r/OcVN5r/2

Below is the R codes I have tried so far and neither works.

```
library(stringr)
patt = "dear\\s+(mr|mrs|miss|ms)\\b[^£]+(£[\\d,.]+)(?:\\D|\\d(?![\\d.]*%))+([\\d.]+%)(?:\\D|\\d(?![\\d.]*%))+([\\d.]+%)"
str_extract(text, patt)
grepl(pattern = patt, x = text)
```

I'm getting an error saying the regex is wrong but it works on the website. Not sure how to get it to work in r. 
Basically I am trying to extract pieces of information from the text. Below are the details:
From the above dataframe, I need to extract the following:

1: Gender of the person. In this case it would be Male (looking at `Mr`)

2: The number that represents the property value. in this case would be `£500,000.00`.

3: The protected percentage value, which in our case would be `0%`.

4: The interest rate value and in our case it is `4.8%`.

Comment: Try using the `perl=TRUE` option? The regex is wrong because it is in perl format. Enabling perl option will run this code.

Comment: If you want to extract you can't use `grep`. Use `str_match_all` from `stringr`.

Comment: Can you specify what package is `str_extract` from?

Comment: It's from the 'stringr' package @JayCe

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Note that your text to search is `text$text`, not simply `text`. You're trying to search in a column of a data frame. (Might want to switch up some names to avoid confusion)

Comment: I don't get an error when I use str_extract () but the regex doesn't find any matches, when clearly there are as found by the website https://regex101.com/r/OcVN5r/2 . Basically it's the 'Match information' on the right side that shows the matches and are exactly what I want to extract.

Comment: Thanks @Camille. You are right it should be text$text. I changed it but still the regex is not finding any matches.

Comment: You also might want to concatenate the bits of text in that vector. Right now you're searching for the full phrase in each element in the vector. Try `paste(text$text, collapse = " ")`, then search within that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is your regex isn't giving alternate or "OR" matches. See below based on your bullet list

```
library(stringi)
rgx <- "(?<=dear\\s?)(m(r(s)?|s|iss))|\\p{S}([0-9]\\S+)|([0-9]+)((\\.[0-9]{1,})?)\\%"
stri_extract_all_regex(
   text$text, rgx, opts_regex = stri_opts_regex(case_insensitive = T)
) %>% unlist()
```

Which gives

```
[1] "Mr"          "£500,000.00"      "0%"          "4.8%"
```

The pattern says:

- `"(?<=dear\\s?)(m(r(s)?|s|iss))"` = ***find a match where the word dear appears before a mr, ms, mrs or miss... but don't capture the dear or the leading space***
- `|` = ***OR***
- `"\\p{S}([0-9]\\S+)"` = ***find a match where a sequence of numbers occurs, after a symbol (see ?stringi-search-charclass), until there is a white space. But It must have a symbol at the beginning***
- `|` = ***OR***
- `"([0-9]+)((\\.[0-9]{1,})?)\\%"` = ***find a match where a number occurs one or more times, that may have a decimal with numbers after it, but will end in a percent sign***

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with `regexpr` function.

For an example:

```
text = "Dear Mr case 1, the value of my property is £500,000.00 and it was built in 1980, The protected percentage is 13% for 2 years, The interest rate is fixed for 2 years at 4.8%";

grps <- regexpr (pattern=patt, text = text, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE);

start_idx <- attr (grps, "capture.start");
end_idx   <- start_idx + attr (grps, "capture.length");

substring (text = text, first = start_idx, last = end_idx);
```

This matches: `[1] "Mr "          "£500,000.00 " "13% "         "4.8%"`

From the manual:

> **regexpr** returns an integer vector of the same length as text giving the starting position of the first match or -1 if there is
>   none, with attribute "match.length", an integer vector giving the
>   length of the matched text (or -1 for no match). The match positions
>   and lengths are in characters unless useBytes = TRUE is used, when
>   they are in bytes (as they are for an ASCII-only matching: in either
>   case an attribute useBytes with value TRUE is set on the result). If
>   named capture is used there are further attributes "capture.start",
>   "capture.length" and "capture.names".
>
> **gregexpr** returns a list of the same length as text each element of
>   which is of the same form as the return value for regexpr, except that
>   the starting positions of every (disjoint) match are given.

In your case I think you need to paste the lines together by using

```
full_line <- paste (text[,"text"], collapse=" ");
```

Then apply `regexpr` on `full_line`